# Issue with decryption while calling credentialssaved in registry using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, registry

I have created a registry file to save Azure Password.

```
$path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\PowerShellCred"
$sec = Read-Host "Enter Password for $name" -AsSecureString
$hash = $sec | ConvertFrom-SecureString
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $admin -Value $hash -Force
```

but on calling the password, i am having trouble in in decrypting the password using ConvertTo-SecureString. I am using the same user Account to create password and Access it(Admin)

```
$admin = "xxxxxx@xxxx.com"
$pass = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)."$name"
$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$c = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($admin, $secpw)
$Azurelogin = Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $c
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have stored in the registry is an **encrypted** string, not real `PlainText`.
Something like `01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000001a114d45b8dd3f4aa11ad7c0abdae9800000000002000000000003660000a8000000100000005df63cea84bfb7d70bd6842e7
efa79820000000004800000a000000010000000f10cd0f4a99a8d5814d94e0687d7430b100000008bf11f1960158405b2779613e9352c6d14000000e6b7bf46a9d485ff211b9b2a2df3bd
6eb67aae41`

To convert that back into a SecureString, you do not use the switches `-AsPlainText` and `-Force` as you would when converting a 'normal' string like `P@ssW@rd`.

Try

```
$secpw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass
```